# Why does my DIV clip its child DIV when jQuery moves it in IE?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, positioning

I have two divs, both with `position:absolute;`, one inside the other. The parent isn't in a place where it can be set as `position:relative` without an extra layer of complexity (there are a lot of other elements around it that I'd have to account for to put it where it needs to be, which is at the very top of the page, over everything). The child element is made to stick off the bottom of the parent.

In Chrome, Safari, Firefox, it all works splendidly.

In IE, it works until jQuery moves the parent element - at which point the parent element clips the child, so you can barely see the top of the child. I feel like I've read about this, about IE clipping child elements, but I can't seem to find an answer that applies to my case.

It's pretty simple, basically:

```
<div id="parent" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
    [content]
    <div id="tab" style="position:absolute;bottom:-30px;left:0;width:64px;height:32px;background-image:(...);"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#tab").click(function() {
            $("#parent").animate({"top":"-50px"},300);
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you explicitly set the height of the `parent` element you shouldn't have issues anymore.  If you don't know at render time what the height should be (IE it's dynamic content), something like this should work:

```
$('#parent').height(function() { 
   var parentHeight = 0;
   $('#parent').children().each(function() { 
       parentHeight += $(this).height();
   });
   return parentHeight;
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't I just use `$("#parent").css({"height":$("#parent").height()});`? As far as I understand, that value is calculated, not just taken from the CSS. In fact, I did that, and it does seem to apply the proper height as an explicit CSS value, but it doesn't seem to solve my clipping problem. The problem with your solution is that I have a lot of children, not all of which are vertically stacked, so it seems like that wouldn't generate the right number...

Comment: `Padding-bottom` would still fill in the background with `parent`'s `background-color`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it would, but you could get around this issue by wrapping everything inside of `parent` with a `<div class="wrapper">[content]</div>` and setting the background color to that.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea. I'm still - I still feel like this should work, though, and I'd like to find out why it doesn't at least.

Comment: Used the wrapper div idea. Works great for the most part, but now the button's disappeared from IE7! It works fine in 8, and Adobe Browser Lab shows it in 6. But I don't even know where the button is going in 7.

Comment: Where is the button?  Maybe you should update your question with the current code.